# How to convert my multi-dimensional array to a 1-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, flatten

I have a problem in my array.

My array looks like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12]]
```

I have tried using `array_merge()` to merge into one array.

I have tried to merge array with `array_combine()`, but it still don't merge.

I want my array becomes like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Comment: Your php code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function recursive_merge_array($array) {
  $resArray = array();
  $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
  foreach($it as $v) {
    $resArray[] = $v;
  }

  return $resArray;
}

$myArrays = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12]];
$mergedArrays = recursive_merge_array($myArrays);
print_r($mergedArrays);
```

Comment: Why that long since you can do it in 2 lines?

Comment: it's modular, the function can be moved around.

Comment: it works, thankyou very much

Answer (score -1):

This works, but i'm not 100% if its the best solution for this problem...

```
$orignalArray = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12]];

$newArray = array();

foreach ($orignalArray as $child){
    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $child);
}

print_r($newArray);
```